# Stripe Connect w/ React

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm trying to follow the Stripe docs for setting up Connect in my React application.

I add my endpoint URI, and when the user finishes providing the necessary information, Stripe sends them back to my redirect_uri address and provides an authorization code.

My url looks like this

`http://localhost:3000/upload?code={AUTHORIZATION_CODE}&state=abcde12345`

I get to step 3 and am getting stuck.

[image]

In `componentDidMount` I'm trying the following

```
componentDidMount() {
    window
      .fetch("https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token", {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          code: this.props.query.code,
          grant_type: "authorization_code"
        })
      })
      .then(response => console.log(response));
  }
```

But am getting the following error

[image]

I'm in test mode so I'm not sure if there is something I'm not setting up correctly in the dashboard or what.

This is what I'm seeing in the Connect dashboard settings

[image]

Do I need to submit an account application for this to work?

Comment: Here is the guide for React app https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/elements-react

Comment: The one (i think) you followed is for Express and is server-side.

Comment: You *have* to make that request from your backend server because it uses your secret API key. It's impossible to make it directly from your web page, that's why you get the error.

Comment: your page should e.g. get the authorization code and POST it to your backend server, which makes the request to Stripe.

Comment: Just curious were you able to make it work using react elements?

Answer (score 1):

So the issue here is that you are missing access-control-allow-origin header in your request. You can add this line to your headers:

```
headers: {
          Access-Control-Allow-Origin:: "https://connect.stripe.com",
        },
```

Or you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe at the moment. This way should be more convenient.
Don't forget to set redirect URI at https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/applications.

I was struggling with stripe and found your question. I don`t think that you need my answer but maybe somebody else does.